# Windows Update powershell

Tags: powershell, windows-update

I want to make a powershell script that automaticly install all Windows Update, but im having some trouble getting is right.
My script works fine but the only issue im having is that the script still needs user input to work.
I have tried multiple parameters to force the install but every parameter still forces me to comfirm the action.

the user input:

Confirm
Are you sure you want to perform this action?
Performing the operation "(xxxxxxx) Microsoft - Other hardware - Xbox Wireless Adapter for Windows[212KB]"
on target "DESKTOP-xxxxxxx".
[Y] Yes  [A] Yes to All  [N] No  [L] No to All  [S] Suspend  [?] Help (default is "Y"):

the script i'm using.

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted Install-Module PSWindowsUpdate Start-Transcript -Path "C:\temp\" Get-WindowsUpdate Install-WindowsUpdate Get-WindowsUpdate install  IgnoreUserInput -acceptall -AutoReboot
```

can you help me to get the correct parameter to force the install of the updates?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to write "oneliner", you must correctly separate script lines by ";".

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted; Install-Module PSWindowsUpdate; Start-Transcript -Path "C:\temp\filename.txt"; Get-WindowsUpdate; Install-WindowsUpdate -IgnoreUserInput -acceptall -AutoReboot -ForceInstall
```

When you start-transcript use path to file (not to directory).
Use -ForceInstall parameter.